# Google app engine: How to include javascript located in "/static/js" directory

Tags: google-app-engine, templates

I include a javascript program in an HTML file, however, the Google template engine doesn't seem to be able to find it. The "program.js" is stored in the "/static/js" directory of the application, and the "{% include ... %}" command is used in "base.html" as follows. But nothing is included whatsoever. What was the problem? Thanks.

base.html:

```
<html ...>
...
<script>
{% include "/static/js/program.js" %}
</script>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set the folder of the javascript in your app.yaml to the static handlers
This way your app will be able to serve files from that url

```
handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Then address to it normally in the HTML template file or code:

```
<html>
  <script src="/static/js/myscript.js" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your includes in the template directory of your project to use it as inline javascript.
This results in :

```
{% include "program.js" %}

or using :

/templates
/static/js


{% include "../static/js/program.js" %}
```

Now you can use jinja tags in your javascript.